Formally find the domain of convergence of $\sum_{p\in P}x^p$ where P is the set of Prime numbers
I want to say that the radius of converge of this series is the same as $\sum x^n$, 1, but I can't directly use theorems such as Cauchy-Hadamard's theorem or Delambert's theorem, because the series in question is not in the form of $\sum a_nx^n$.
How can I formally show that the radius of convergence is 1? (Btw, it's Calc 2, so please don't show me stuff from higher level courses)

Think a bit more about your claim at the end of your first paragraph. Are you sure it is not of the form?

Yes because we don't all the of natural numbers as exponents - just the prime ones out of them.

So, $a_n=0$ if $n$ is composite, and $a_n=1$ if $n$ is prime.

In any case:  can you see that your series diverges if $x=1$?  Well, what can you say if $|x|<1$?

Oh.... I see now, @lulu. Cauchy Hadamard's theorem only requires limsup, and my limsup is indeed 1 in this case, the other partial limit being 0. Thanks!

Can't you note that
$$\Big|\sum_{p \in P} x^p\Big| \quad \le \quad \sum_{p \in P} |x|^p$$
$$\le \quad \Big(\sum_{p \in P} |x|^p + \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus P} |x|^n\Big)$$ $$\quad = \quad \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x|^n$$
[the latter inequality follows because each $|x|^n$ is nonnegative and $P \subseteq \mathbb{N}$], to conclude that the radius of convergence is at least $1$?
And then note that for any $x > 1$ and any $M > 0$ [no matter how large] that there is a $p \in P$ such that $|x^p| \ge M$ [indeed let $N$ be an integer s.t. $|x|^N  < M$ and and let $p \in P$ satisfy $p >N$; as there are an infinite number of primes there indeed is such a prime $p$], so that the radius of convergence cannot be larger than $1$. Finally for $x$ satisfying $|x|=1$ note that $|x^p|$ stays $1$ for all $p \in P$ so $\sum_{p \in P} x^p$ is an infinite sum of terms all with absolute value $1$ so no convergence here either. [Not needed to show radius of convergence but included for completeness.]
ETA Fun Fact: Since every prime $p \in P$ except $p=2$ is odd, you could also note that for all negative $x$ the equation $x^p = -|x|^p$ holds for all $p \in P \setminus \{2\}$, so no convergence for any $x$ satisfying $|x| \ge 1$; if $x \le -1$ you are taking an infinite sum of all terms [except the first] negative and with absolute value $\ge 1$, and if $x \ge 1$ you are taking an infinite sum of all terms positive and $\ge 1$. This is what you can observe, if you still happen to be queasy about taking an infinite sum possibly consisting of an infinite number of positive and an infinite number of negative terms. But as in the previous paragraph, all you really need is $P$ an infinite set and $|x^p|$ not vanishing as $p \in P$ increases for $|x| \ge 1$.

You probably meant $x^p$, not $x^P$

@jjagmath I made that typo several times. Thanks for catching it!

The radius of convergence of a power series is equal to $$\sup\{|x|\,:\, \lim a_nx^n=0\}$$ If $a_n=1$ for $n\in A$ and $a_n=0$ when $n\notin A,$ for an infinite set $A,$ then $a_nx^n\to 0$ when $|x|<1.$ For $ |x|\ge  1$ we have $|a_nx^n|\ge 1$ for $n\in A.$ Hence the radius of convergence is equal $1.$
